# Show "Local Area Connection" Properties dialog

Tags: c++, windows, networking, network-programming

How I can show the "Local Area Connection" properties dialog from program?

Comment: Which connection do you want? Your machine may have multiple. And they can have any name?

Comment: it does not matter, it can be shown by name

Comment: So you'll provide the name? Or do you want the names to be enumerated?

Comment: Yes, I have the name of connection, and I want show only the properties dialog

Comment: And to be sure we talk about the same thing, it has a page control titled "General", a section named "Connection" with a "Details" button and a section named "Activity". Is that the one? Or is it the dialog you get when you click the "Properties" button on the dialog I described? That one has two tabs, "Networking" and "Sharing".

Comment: It is the dialog where have two tabs "Networking" and "Sharing"

Comment: OK, that's the one that needs UAC elevation.